# LaGrange Multiplier Derivative vs Function

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Why do LaGrange Multipliers produce functional extrema when they look for derivative extrema? I see the process of setting constraint and function gradient vectors equal with lambda as a scaling factor and using the original constraint to solve the system. Doesn't this just yield points of highest gradient and not necessarily points of extreme value for the original function? 
I can't see any other questions on this so I feel I may be wildly misinterpreting something.

Comment: Maybe it would help to look at a simple example, such as minimizing $f(x,y)$ subject to $h(x,y) = 1$, where $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ and $h(x,y) = y$. Clearly the optimal point is $(0,1)$. At this point, the gradient of $f$ is $(0,2)$ and the gradient of $h$ is $(0,1)$. You can see that $\nabla f(x,y)$ is a scalar multiple of $\nabla h(x,y)$ at the optimal point.

Comment: To calrify and summarize my question, would it not be possible to have a function with a relatively low value but a very high gradient along the constraint boundary that produces a "dud" so to speak?

Comment: The Lagrange multiplier optimality condition tells you something about the direction of $\nabla f(x)$. It doesn't say anything about the magnitude of $\nabla f(x)$.

Comment: What do you mean by “look for derivative extrema?” At its core, the Lagrange multiplier method relies on the same principle as that underlying the method you learned for finding local extrema of a single-variable function back in an elementary course: You look for points at which the derivative (here, taken in a particular direction) vanishes.